# AWS cant connect to vm inside vpc

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am trying to create a VPC without the wizard.

I added the routes, internet gateway, NACL and Security groups but my vm remains unreachable, below I have posted details from the aws cli to give you precise details.

I have  a feeling that it has something to do with my routes. I am unable to ping or ssh into my jumpbox

Architecture Diagram:-

[image]

```
yamazaki@yamazaki-linux:~$ aws ec2 describe-security-groups --group-ids sg-ab7a71cd
{
    "SecurityGroups": [
        {
            "IpPermissionsEgress": [
                {
                    "IpProtocol": "-1", 
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                        }
                    ], 
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": [], 
                    "PrefixListIds": []
                }
            ], 
            "Description": "mysg", 
            "IpPermissions": [
                {
                    "PrefixListIds": [], 
                    "FromPort": 22, 
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                        }
                    ], 
                    "ToPort": 22, 
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp", 
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": []
                }, 
                {
                    "PrefixListIds": [], 
                    "FromPort": -1, 
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                        }
                    ], 
                    "ToPort": -1, 
                    "IpProtocol": "icmp", 
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": []
                }
            ], 
            "GroupName": "mysg", 
            "VpcId": "vpc-220e9346", 
            "OwnerId": "646132786531", 
            "GroupId": "sg-ab7a71cd"
        }
    ]
}

yamazaki@yamazaki-linux:~$ aws ec2 describe-network-acls --network-acl-ids acl-1816717c
{
    "NetworkAcls": [
        {
            "Associations": [
                {
                    "SubnetId": "subnet-91a025ac", 
                    "NetworkAclId": "acl-1816717c", 
                    "NetworkAclAssociationId": "aclassoc-78fa7001"
                }, 
                {
                    "SubnetId": "subnet-aea02593", 
                    "NetworkAclId": "acl-1816717c", 
                    "NetworkAclAssociationId": "aclassoc-ede56f94"
                }, 
                {
                    "SubnetId": "subnet-6da02550", 
                    "NetworkAclId": "acl-1816717c", 
                    "NetworkAclAssociationId": "aclassoc-19e46e60"
                }
            ], 
            "NetworkAclId": "acl-1816717c", 
            "VpcId": "vpc-220e9346", 
            "Tags": [], 
            "Entries": [
                {
                    "CidrBlock": "0.0.0.0/0", 
                    "RuleNumber": 100, 
                    "Protocol": "-1", 
                    "Egress": true, 
                    "RuleAction": "allow"
                }, 
                {
                    "CidrBlock": "0.0.0.0/0", 
                    "RuleNumber": 32767, 
                    "Protocol": "-1", 
                    "Egress": true, 
                    "RuleAction": "deny"
                }, 
                {
                    "RuleNumber": 100, 
                    "Protocol": "6", 
                    "PortRange": {
                        "To": 22, 
                        "From": 22
                    }, 
                    "Egress": false, 
                    "RuleAction": "allow", 
                    "CidrBlock": "0.0.0.0/0"
                }, 
                {
                    "IcmpTypeCode": {
                        "Code": -1, 
                        "Type": -1
                    }, 
                    "RuleNumber": 200, 
                    "Protocol": "1", 
                    "Egress": false, 
                    "RuleAction": "allow", 
                    "CidrBlock": "0.0.0.0/0"
                }, 
                {
                    "CidrBlock": "0.0.0.0/0", 
                    "RuleNumber": 32767, 
                    "Protocol": "-1", 
                    "Egress": false, 
                    "RuleAction": "deny"
                }
            ], 
            "IsDefault": true
        }
    ]


yamazaki@yamazaki-linux:~$ aws ec2 describe-vpcs --vpc-id vpc-220e9346
{
    "Vpcs": [
        {
            "VpcId": "vpc-220e9346", 
            "InstanceTenancy": "default", 
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Value": "big", 
                    "Key": "Name"
                }
            ], 
            "State": "available", 
            "DhcpOptionsId": "dopt-80c96ce5", 
            "CidrBlock": "192.168.0.0/20", 
            "IsDefault": false
        }
    ]
}


yamazaki@yamazaki-linux:~$ aws ec2 describe-subnets --subnet-ids subnet-6da02550 subnet-aea02593 subnet-91a025ac
{
    "Subnets": [
        {                                                                                                                                                                                                  
            "VpcId": "vpc-220e9346",                                                                                                                                                                       
            "Tags": [                                                                                                                                                                                      
                {                                                                                                                                                                                          
                    "Value": "big-private-databases",                                                                                                                                                      
                    "Key": "Name"                                                                                                                                                                          
                }                                                                                                                                                                                          
            ],                                                                                                                                                                                             
            "CidrBlock": "192.168.3.0/24", 
            "MapPublicIpOnLaunch": false, 
            "DefaultForAz": false, 
            "State": "available", 
            "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-1e", 
            "SubnetId": "subnet-91a025ac", 
            "AvailableIpAddressCount": 251
        }, 
        {
            "VpcId": "vpc-220e9346", 
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Value": "big-internet", 
                    "Key": "Name"
                }
            ], 
            "CidrBlock": "192.168.1.0/24", 
            "MapPublicIpOnLaunch": false, 
            "DefaultForAz": false, 
            "State": "available", 
            "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-1e", 
            "SubnetId": "subnet-6da02550", 
            "AvailableIpAddressCount": 250
        }, 
        {
            "VpcId": "vpc-220e9346", 
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Value": "big-private-computes", 
                    "Key": "Name"
                }
            ], 
            "CidrBlock": "192.168.2.0/24", 
            "MapPublicIpOnLaunch": false, 
            "DefaultForAz": false, 
            "State": "available", 
            "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-1e", 
            "SubnetId": "subnet-aea02593", 
            "AvailableIpAddressCount": 250
        }
    ]
}

yamazaki@yamazaki-linux:~$ aws ec2 describe-route-tables --route-table-ids rtb-fb83c99f rtb-1eb9f37a rtb-c980caad rtb-9980cafd
{
    "RouteTables": [
        {
            "Associations": [], 
            "RouteTableId": "rtb-fb83c99f", 
            "VpcId": "vpc-220e9346", 
            "PropagatingVgws": [], 
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Value": "big-in", 
                    "Key": "Name"
                }
            ], 
            "Routes": [
                {
                    "GatewayId": "local", 
                    "DestinationCidrBlock": "192.168.0.0/20", 
                    "State": "active", 
                    "Origin": "CreateRouteTable"
                }, 
                {
                    "GatewayId": "igw-51638f35", 
                    "DestinationCidrBlock": "0.0.0.0/0", 
                    "State": "active", 
                    "Origin": "CreateRoute"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "Associations": [
                {
                    "RouteTableAssociationId": "rtbassoc-0113ef66", 
                    "Main": true, 
                    "RouteTableId": "rtb-1eb9f37a"
                }
            ], 
            "RouteTableId": "rtb-1eb9f37a", 
            "VpcId": "vpc-220e9346", 
            "PropagatingVgws": [], 
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Value": "big", 
                    "Key": "Name"
                }
            ], 
            "Routes": [
                {
                    "GatewayId": "local", 
                    "DestinationCidrBlock": "192.168.0.0/20", 
                    "State": "active", 
                    "Origin": "CreateRouteTable"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "Associations": [], 
            "RouteTableId": "rtb-c980caad", 
            "VpcId": "vpc-220e9346", 
            "PropagatingVgws": [], 
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Value": "big-in-computes", 
                    "Key": "Name"
                }
            ], 
            "Routes": [
                {
                    "GatewayId": "local", 
                    "DestinationCidrBlock": "192.168.0.0/20", 
                    "State": "active", 
                    "Origin": "CreateRouteTable"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "Associations": [], 
            "RouteTableId": "rtb-9980cafd", 
            "VpcId": "vpc-220e9346", 
            "PropagatingVgws": [], 
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Value": "big-computes-databases", 
                    "Key": "Name"
                }
            ], 
            "Routes": [
                {
                    "GatewayId": "local", 
                    "DestinationCidrBlock": "192.168.0.0/20", 
                    "State": "active", 
                    "Origin": "CreateRouteTable"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

yamazaki@yamazaki-linux:~$ aws ec2 describe-internet-gateways --internet-gateway-ids igw-51638f35
{
    "InternetGateways": [
        {
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Value": "big", 
                    "Key": "Name"
                }
            ], 
            "InternetGatewayId": "igw-51638f35", 
            "Attachments": [
                {
                    "State": "available", 
                    "VpcId": "vpc-220e9346"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

yamazaki@yamazaki-linux:~$ aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids --instance-ids i-3c6c09c5
{
    "Reservations": [
        {
            "OwnerId": "646132786531", 
            "ReservationId": "r-12f788fb", 
            "Groups": [], 
            "Instances": [
                {
                    "Monitoring": {
                        "State": "disabled"
                    }, 
                    "PublicDnsName": "", 
                    "State": {
                        "Code": 16, 
                        "Name": "running"
                    }, 
                    "EbsOptimized": false, 
                    "LaunchTime": "2015-12-10T16:30:41.000Z", 
                    "PublicIpAddress": "52.70.141.142", 
                    "PrivateIpAddress": "192.168.1.67", 
                    "ProductCodes": [], 
                    "VpcId": "vpc-220e9346", 
                    "StateTransitionReason": "", 
                    "InstanceId": "i-3c6c09c5", 
                    "ImageId": "ami-60b6c60a", 
                    "PrivateDnsName": "ip-192-168-1-67.ec2.internal", 
                    "KeyName": "yamazaki", 
                    "SecurityGroups": [
                        {
                            "GroupName": "mysg", 
                            "GroupId": "sg-ab7a71cd"
                        }
                    ], 
                    "ClientToken": "DpGNG1449765041380", 
                    "SubnetId": "subnet-6da02550", 
                    "InstanceType": "t2.micro", 
                    "NetworkInterfaces": [
                        {
                            "Status": "in-use", 
                            "MacAddress": "06:1a:f4:6a:b6:f5", 
                            "SourceDestCheck": true, 
                            "VpcId": "vpc-220e9346", 
                            "Description": "Primary network interface", 
                            "Association": {
                                "PublicIp": "52.70.141.142", 
                                "PublicDnsName": "", 
                                "IpOwnerId": "646132786531"
                            }, 
                            "NetworkInterfaceId": "eni-971b94ab", 
                            "PrivateIpAddresses": [
                                {
                                    "Association": {
                                        "PublicIp": "52.70.141.142", 
                                        "PublicDnsName": "", 
                                        "IpOwnerId": "646132786531"
                                    }, 
                                    "Primary": true, 
                                    "PrivateIpAddress": "192.168.1.67"
                                }
                            ], 
                            "Attachment": {
                                "Status": "attached", 
                                "DeviceIndex": 0, 
                                "DeleteOnTermination": true, 
                                "AttachmentId": "eni-attach-cdd36cbc", 
                                "AttachTime": "2015-12-10T16:30:41.000Z"
                            }, 
                            "Groups": [
                                {
                                    "GroupName": "mysg", 
                                    "GroupId": "sg-ab7a71cd"
                                }
                            ], 
                            "SubnetId": "subnet-6da02550", 
                            "OwnerId": "646132786531", 
                            "PrivateIpAddress": "192.168.1.67"
                        }
                    ], 
                    "SourceDestCheck": true, 
                    "Placement": {
                        "Tenancy": "default", 
                        "GroupName": "", 
                        "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-1e"
                    }, 
                    "Hypervisor": "xen", 
                    "BlockDeviceMappings": [
                        {
                            "DeviceName": "/dev/xvda", 
                            "Ebs": {
                                "Status": "attached", 
                                "DeleteOnTermination": true, 
                                "VolumeId": "vol-5ade4392", 
                                "AttachTime": "2015-12-10T16:30:45.000Z"
                            }
                        }
                    ], 
                    "Architecture": "x86_64", 
                    "RootDeviceType": "ebs", 
                    "RootDeviceName": "/dev/xvda", 
                    "VirtualizationType": "hvm", 
                    "Tags": [
                        {
                            "Value": "jumpbox", 
                            "Key": "Name"
                        }
                    ], 
                    "AmiLaunchIndex": 0
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

Comment: can you set all network ACLs rules as default and remove `RuleNumber` 100 and 200?

Answer (score 1):

After adding a subnet association for the route table with the one with the internet gateway I was able to connect to my box.

```
aws ec2 describe-route-tables --route-table-ids rtb-fb83c99f
{
    "RouteTables": [
        {
            "Associations": [
                {
                    "SubnetId": "subnet-6da02550", 
                    "RouteTableAssociationId": "rtbassoc-48a35d2f", 
                    "Main": false, 
                    "RouteTableId": "rtb-fb83c99f"
                }
            ], 
            "RouteTableId": "rtb-fb83c99f", 
            "VpcId": "vpc-220e9346", 
            "PropagatingVgws": [], 
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Value": "big-in", 
                    "Key": "Name"
                }
            ], 
            "Routes": [
                {
                    "GatewayId": "local", 
                    "DestinationCidrBlock": "192.168.0.0/20", 
                    "State": "active", 
                    "Origin": "CreateRouteTable"
                }, 
                {
                    "GatewayId": "igw-51638f35", 
                    "DestinationCidrBlock": "0.0.0.0/0", 
                    "State": "active", 
                    "Origin": "CreateRoute"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```